# Wierd..object get duplicated in arrylist when 'step over' debugger tool cliked

Tags: android, json, arraylist

This is quite hard to explain but.. this code is supposed to add items from a JSON array and display on a ListView. the pages is refreshed using the onResume method that i ahve overwritten

```
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (adapter != null) {
        newItemlist.clear();
        newItemlist.addAll(getJsonData());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //newItemlist.clear();
    }
}
```

All this should do is display contents from a JSON Object. Below is whole class.

```
public class LogFragment extends Fragment {

Cursor cursor;
ListView listV;
String json;
SimpleAdapter adapter;
SharedPreferences exmaplePrefs;
public static final String PREFS = "examplePrefs";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newItemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public LogFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // getJsonData();

    String from[] = { "time", "event", "player" };
    int to[] = { R.id.time, R.id.event, R.id.player };
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), newItemlist,
            R.layout.custom_list_row, from, to);

}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getJsonData() {
    exmaplePrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
    json = exmaplePrefs.getString("jsonString", "cant find json");
    JSONObject MainObj = null;
    JSONArray JsonArray = null;
    JSONObject temp = null;

    try {

        MainObj = new JSONObject(json);
        JsonArray = MainObj.optJSONArray("Events");
        if (JsonArray == null) {
            temp = MainObj.getJSONObject("Events");

            String time = temp.getString("time");
            String event = temp.getString("event");
            String player = temp.getString("player");

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("time", time);
            map.put("event", event);
            map.put("player", player);
            newItemlist.add(map);

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < JsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = JsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                String time = c.getString("time");
                String event = c.getString("event");
                String player = c.getString("player");

                // Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("time", time);
                map.put("event", event);
                map.put("player", player);
                newItemlist.add(map);

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.print("ERROR");
    }
    return newItemlist;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container,
            false);
    listV = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listV.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (adapter != null) {
        newItemlist.clear();
        newItemlist.addAll(getJsonData());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //newItemlist.clear();
    }
}
```

The problem i was having is that items were being duplicated e.g if i clicked item1 then the display would show item1 item1. if i then clicked item2 the display would be item1 item2 item1 item2.

This leads me on to the weird problem. when debugging the more I step through the code....the more duplicates are made! i.e. stepped over 15 lines and  below is the result.

[{item1=ONE}, {item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},{item1=ONE},]

Comment: `getJsonData` returns `newItemlist`. I'm not sure what `newItemlist.addAll` would do in this case. (but it surely duplicates the items.)

Comment: yes your right, i cant believe i didn't see that. I call getJsonData(); rather than newItemlist.addAll(getJsonData());.

Still dont see how this affected the debugger "/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple :

- Step A, you clear `newItemlist`
- Step B, you add items in `newItemlist`
- Step C, you return `newItemlist` from `getJsonData`
- Step D, you add all items from `getJsonData` in `newItemList`

Your items are duplicated.